# Beta Package Release Error

Tags: salesforce

I have installed beta package on test org. Now i have released another beta package.
But while installing it in test org it is now allowing to install.

So, Can we install Beta version on existing beta package?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is an upgrade to an existing managed package you must first uninstall the current version.